# How can I do a lexical string compare >= with an SQL Server database, EF Core and LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq, ef-core-3.1

I want to do a query in C# (EF Core and LINQ), where the query is structured like this:

```
SELECT someField
  FROM SomeTable
  WHERE someField >= 'A 100' AND someField <= 'A 150'
```

The SQL works just fine, but I cannot find a way to translate that into LINQ with EF Core.

The 2 strings should be string parameters for the query.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. lambda-expression like `.Where(s => s.someField >= lowerBoundary)`. **Problem:** The compiler does not like that at all. [image]
2. Use String.Compare like this 
   `.Where(p => string.Compare(p.someField, searchCriteria.lowerBoundary) >= 0 &&
                                   string.Compare(p.someField, searchCriteria.upperBoundary) <= 0);` 
   ** Update (edit): This DOES work**. For some reason it did not in my first try when it was mixed up with other parts of my more complex query.

I have used EF Core 3.1.1

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use either == or the contains for comparison.

Comment: The SQL itself is at least slightly dubious -- keep in mind that `A 1000` is "between" `A 100` and `A 150` as well. Make sure it keeps working "fine" even if your data should change.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, I am aware of the fact that I am abusing strings for something that looks like a number. ;-) But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @SurajKumar Neither of those operators would solve my issue. I want to get a range back based on a lexical comparison.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It did. But I was wrong in my question as I just found out. My second try with "String.Compare" did work when I implemented it in isolation from the other parts of my (more complex) query. I will have to edit my question. Thanks!